# How to solve 500 internal server error in custom module in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, magento-2.0.7, http-error-500

My php version is 5.6

> **PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_curl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/php_curl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0**

After each magento2 command i am getting above warning, and in my custom module i am getting 500 internal server error while connecting to controller. But at other system with php version 7, my  module is working fine. **Is this error and warning is related to each other?** What is the exactly solution of this? Please explain anybody

Comment: Magento 2 is designed for php 7+, why not update it?

Comment: You need to install curl extension for your php version. However, not sure if that Magento2 version you are using supports php5.6, I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini you need to do the following as you don't have that extension installed. You can also download the extension with most versions of PHP

Find

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

Change to

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

Answer (score -3):

Try these two commands in SSH in your Magento root directory:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
chmod -R 777 pub var app/etc
```

Comment: his warning clearly states issue is connected to curl lib. it has nothing to do with cache or permissions